# Datadog container unable to connect to redis server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, datadog

I am running the datadog container as one of the services in docker compose. I am running `Agent: 7` for my purposes.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    image: app
    container_name: app
    hostname: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - shared_volume:/tmp/logs

  datadog:
    container_name: dd-agent
    image: gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8125:8125/udp
      - 8126:8126
    environment:
      - DD_API_KEY=${DATADOG_API_KEY}
      - DD_SITE=${DD_SITE}
      - DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=${DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC}
      - DD_LOGS_ENABLED="true"
      - DD_APM_ENABLED="true"
      - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL="true"
      - DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_LOGS="name:dd-agent"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro
      # - /opt/dd-agent/run:/opt/dd-agent/run:rw
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro


volumes:
  shared_volume:
```

However running the datadog container runs into an error. The error log says that it's trying to connect to a redis server. I am not sure where is this coming from, as I don't recollect redis being one of the dependencies for datadog.

[image: error log]

Pasted same log below for convenience -

```
dd-agent  | 2022-10-11 10:13:53 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/worker/check_logger.go:69 in Error) | check:php_fpm | Error running check: [{"message": "Detected 1 error while loading configuration model `InstanceConfig`:\n__root__\n  Field `status_url` or `ping_url` must be set", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1091, in run\n    initialization()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 492, in load_configuration_models\n    instance_config = self.load_configuration_model(package_path, 'InstanceConfig', raw_instance_config)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 536, in load_configuration_model\n    raise_from(ConfigurationError('\\n'.join(message_lines)), None)\n  File \"<string>\", line 3, in raise_from\ndatadog_checks.base.errors.ConfigurationError: Detected 1 error while loading configuration model `InstanceConfig`:\n__root__\n  Field `status_url` or `ping_url` must be set\n"}]
dd-agent  | 2022-10-11 10:13:57 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/worker/check_logger.go:69 in Error) | check:redisdb | Error running check: [{"message": "Timeout connecting to server", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 611, in connect\n    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/retry.py\", line 51, in call_with_retry\n    raise error\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/retry.py\", line 46, in call_with_retry\n    return do()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 612, in <lambda>\n    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 677, in _connect\n    raise err\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 665, in _connect\n    sock.connect(socket_address)\nsocket.timeout: timed out\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1116, in run\n    self.check(instance)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/redisdb/redisdb.py\", line 556, in check\n    self._check_db()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/redisdb/redisdb.py\", line 205, in _check_db\n    info = conn.info()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py\", line 970, in info\n    return self.execute_command(\"INFO\", **kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/client.py\", line 1235, in execute_command\n    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 1387, in get_connection\n    connection.connect()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py\", line 615, in connect\n    raise TimeoutError(\"Timeout connecting to server\")\nredis.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout connecting to server\n"}]
```

Comment: Do you use any redis related stuff in the Dockerfile of your app? Like this label: `LABEL "com.datadoghq.ad.check_names"='["redisdb"]'`

Comment: No! There's nothing as such

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-py/issues/3645), however it does not interfere with the agent collection and sending logs and traces to Datadog.

Here is [a comment](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-py/issues/3645#issuecomment-1232971504) on that same issue

> do not pay attention on this . its do not have any impact on collection and sending data

I ran into the same issue and can confirm that the agent still works. I wish they would fix this or change the error message to a warning with a message "You may disregard this warning".